# Array issues, and where in clause

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm having some trouble trying to use a query result as an array

First i run a query to get all the zips that i need

```
   $this->db->select('zip');
    $this->db->from('custom_city');
    $this->db->join('city_to_zip', 'custom_city.id = city_to_zip.city_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('city_to_zip.city_id', $_POST['city']);
    $zip = $this->db->get();
    $data['zips'] = $zip;

    $zip_array = $zip->result_array();
```

then the query output is this, when i try to use it.

Now i know it's doing something, because it says "array" 8 times and thats the right count for the query. I just need to know how to get the zip code in there instead of the word array.

```
AND `zip_code` IN (Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array) [/quote]
```

in my query i'm using...

```
 $this->db->where_in('zip_code', $zip_array);
```

Thanks,

Jbeasley

Comment: Thank you so much.
 This worked for me.
  $zip_array = array();
  foreach($zip->result() as $row):  {
  $zip_array[] = $row->zip; }
  endforeach;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `result_array()` returns an associative array for each row (so you're getting an array of arrays).  To get the zip codes into `$zip_array`, replace this line:

```
$zip_array = $zip->result_array();
```

with

```
$zip_array = array();
$result = $zip->result_array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $zip_array[] = $row['zip'];
}
```

[Documentation on result_array()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)